# How to bind/wrap an event of a child control to custom control's event, in C#?

Tags: c#, xaml, events, uwp, custom-controls

I'm building a Custom Control (or Templated, if you mind), but I can't figure out how to bind the event (the Click) of a button inside the custom control to the Click event of the Custom Control itself.

I have searched on the internet, but some solution was only for WPF (including classes not available in the UWP platform), some was for Visual Basic, some other wasn't exactly my case and so on...

Here is the code, that works perfectly so far, for best clearance (please note, I have changed the project's and namespace's name to hide it, putting instead "SomeClass"):

The custom control, **IconButton.cs**:

```
public sealed class IconButton : Control
{
    public IconButton()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(IconButton);

    }



    public Boolean IconButtonIsLabelVisible
    {
        get { return (Boolean)GetValue(IconButtonIsLabelVisibleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconButtonIsLabelVisibleProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconButtonIsLabelVisibleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IconButtonIsLabelVisible", typeof(Boolean), typeof(IconButton), new PropertyMetadata(true));



    public String IconButtonLabel
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(IconButtonLabelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconButtonLabelProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconButtonLabelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IconButtonLabel", typeof(String), typeof(IconButton), new PropertyMetadata("Content"));



    public Double IconButtonLabelMargin
    {
        get { return (Double)GetValue(IconButtonLabelMarginProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconButtonLabelMarginProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconButtonLabelMarginProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IconButtonLabelMargin", typeof(Double), typeof(IconButton), new PropertyMetadata(10));



    public Style IconButtonStyle
    {
        get { return (Style)GetValue(IconButtonStyleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconButtonStyleProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconButtonStyleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IconButtonStyle", typeof(Style), typeof(IconButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));



    public IconElement IconButtonIcon
    {
        get { return (IconElement)GetValue(IconButtonIconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconButtonIconProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconButtonIconProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IconButtonIcon", typeof(IconElement), typeof(IconButton), new PropertyMetadata(0));

}
```

The generic xaml template file, **Generic.xaml**:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:SomeClass.Controls">

<Style TargetType="local:IconButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:IconButton">
                <Button x:Name="ClickButton" Style="{TemplateBinding IconButtonStyle}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Command="{TemplateBinding Command}" CommandParameter="{TemplateBinding CommandParameter}">
                    <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding IconButtonIcon}"
                                Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Width="{TemplateBinding IconButtonLabelMargin}"/>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{TemplateBinding IconButtonLabel}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Button>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And the **MainPage.xaml**, where I would like to use the IconButton:

```
<Page
x:Class="SomeClass"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:SomeClass"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
xmlns:testControls="using:SomeClass.Controls"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>
    <testControls:IconButton x:Name="TestButton" Click"?" IconButtonLabelMargin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Aqua" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" >
        <testControls:IconButton.IconButtonIcon>
            <SymbolIcon Symbol="Preview"/>
        </testControls:IconButton.IconButtonIcon>
    </testControls:IconButton>
</Grid>
```

> So, given this code, I would like to bind in some way the Click event of the ClickButton in
>   the xaml template of the IconButton to the default Click event of the
>   IconButton control itself, so that it can be easily used in the mainpage by
>   simply specifying the Click event.

Thank you for you kindness and your attention.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this requires overriding the `OnApplyTemplate` method in your control, finding the named template part in your control, and raising the event on your wrapper.

Inside your custom control:

```
ButtonBase clickButtonPart = null;
public const string ClickButtonTemplatePartName = "ClickButton";
public event EventHandler Click;

protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
  // In case the template changes, you want to stop listening to the
  // old button's Click event.
  if (clickButtonPart != null)
  {
    clickButtonPart.Click -= ClickForwarder;
    clickButtonPart = null;
  }

  // Find the template child with the special name. It can be any kind
  // of ButtonBase in this example.
  clickButtonPart = GetTemplateChild(ClickButtonTemplatePartName) as ButtonBase;

  // Add a handler to its Click event that simply forwards it on to our
  // Click event.
  if (clickButtonPart != null)
  {
    clickButtonPart.Click += ClickForwarder;
  }
}

private void ClickForwarder(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Click?.Invoke(this, null);
}
```